# Get URI Portion After Tomcat Container Name

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

If I have a tomcat application (lets call it Testing for examples sake). How do I capture the URI portion of the string after the Tomcat name?

```
http://localhost:8080/Testing/app/d/123/
request.getRequestURL().toString();   # returns http://localhost:8080/Testing/app/d/123/
request.getRequestURI();              # returns /Testing/app/d/123/
```

In a production environment, the Tomcat application name (Testing) obviously won't be there. I'd like to capture specific portions of the URL and the data between the first 2 forward slashes will be important. Without specifying to remove the /Testing/ portion by doing a replace, is there a way to automatically return only the portion of the URL after testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED

Try:

```
request.getPathInfo();
```

It will give you the part of your url without the server address, port and context where the application is installed.

Comment: Hmm..that returns just /Testing. Will the context of a domain http://testing.com/app/d/123/ return an empty string? So it would be safe to always remove the context path portion of the string?

Comment: @ryandlf sorry, I misunderstood your question. Answer edited.

Comment: Perfect. Will accept in a few minutes when allowed. Thanks for the quick response.